# Perl Carp confess not terminating application

Tags: perl, error-handling

I have an module which uses 
`Carp::confess "<message here>"` (Assume this statement is in subroutine B). As per my interpretation, the message would be output to STDERR and the application should terminate at that point. However application doesn't terminate. I put a print statements before and after the confess statement just to ensure that the confess statement does get executed. 
I even checked if the subroutine A which calls subroutine has an eval{} block defined to catch the error and not act on it. But it doesn't seem to be the case.

Are there other scenarios where Carp::confess will not terminate the program? I am bit confused regarding this.

Thank-you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval BLOCK`, `eval EXPR`, `do EXPR` and XS code calling Perl code are the only things capable of catching exceptions.

It's also possible that an exception was thrown in the first place, such as when `die` is very badly overridden.